# D7 : Upload to a folder outside of "files" folder?

Tags: entities, files

Specifically outside of the Drupal installation folder...

I have a folder in my WWW folder that I'd like place files into through Drupal. However, it looks like, by default Drupal prefers to only upload into the "files" folder.

Has anyone encountered something like this?

I have tried making a custom upload field point to "/var/www/uploads" and the FilePath module, but neither work.

Any suggestions. Is this a case of creating a custom module that points to that folder? If anyone has come across a tutorial regarding custom upload paths that would be awesome.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible by design, for security reasons. Imagine your users being able to overwrite your `/etc/password` or `apache.conf` - horror.

If you need outside storage, you need to use operating system methods, like:

- hard links
- symbolic links
- `mount -o bind`
- junctions
- and probably many other